# Ending of Joyce Carol Oates story "Lady with a pet dog"

Tags: meaning, short-stories

This is a rewritten Chekhov story.

This is the epiphany moment for Anna, when she accepts their love, but the ending is still quite ambiguous.

> Their love beginning again, in spite of them? “How can you look so happy?” he asked. “We don’t have any right to it. Is it because…?”
> “Yes,” she said.”

What did she admit to? In my opinion it has to be something more than simply admitting to love as it was something he already knew. Besides, why did he say "We don’t have any right to it"? It was him in the whole story who was the propulsion of the whole affair so why did he say something which sounds like contradiction?